# I have got a request where only numbers has to be there in output xml file, cut char from the end in xslt(Biztalk Map)

Tags: xslt, mapping, biztalk

This is my input

```
    <ns0:Expiration Calculation>445566Calculate</ns0:Expiration Calculation>
```

Required Output:
'445566'

Requirement: Strings has to be cut from the end.
I have tried replace function, but it is giving error like replace is an unknown function in xslt .

Could any of you help me with the above request.

Thanks,

Comment: If you get an error when using the 'replace' function, you are probably using an XSLT 1.0 engine. You should look into using the 'translate' function.

Comment: Your input is not XML: an element name cannot contain a space.